# Security of Session cookie

Tags: authentication, session, session-cookies

I made an express session like this:

```
app.use(session({
    name: "Session_name",
    secret: "Some secret",
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
```

I only wanted to know whether it is considered secure if the name of session appears like this in the Network(in Inspect):

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbIdG.png)

If it is not secure, what can I do so that session's name doesn't appear?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies can be easily modified by the user. Thus you should treat cookies as any other user input.
The cookie name can be public. The secret should be a hash of something unique to the user and the session and impossible to guess.

To discourage script kiddies you can change the cookie name on every request. But that does not really add anything as long as the secret remains secret.